# How i can get the actor id in my java program in drools?

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to develop an application in `drools`,

My `rf` files is the image shown below.

[image]

For the user task ,i have set the actor name as `"MyName"` .

Now i am reading the rules from this file in my `java program.`

I want the `name of actor`.

How i can get the name of actor?

My java code:

```
      TaskServiceSession taskSession = taskService.createSession();

      MinaTaskServer server = new MinaTaskServer( taskService);
      Thread thread = new Thread( server );
      thread.start();
      StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
      HumanTaskHandler handler1 = new HumanTaskHandler();

       ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Log", handler1);
      WSHumanTaskHandler handler = new WSHumanTaskHandler();

      ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", handler);

      KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
      // start a new process instance
      ksession.startProcess("HumanTaskSample");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your handler (HumanTaskHandler) will be called whenever a task needs to be created.  Whenever it is called, you can get all the necessary information from the work item that is passed as a parameter.  So, to get the actor id(s), you can use:

```
public class HumanTaskHandler implements WorkItemHandler {
  public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
    String actorId = (String) workItem.getParameter("ActorId");
    ....
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that, depending on your requirements, there are some other ways of getting to the task as well.  For example, after calling startProcess(..), you could use the returned ProcessInstance to get access to the task id of the task(s) that were created, and then get the full details from the task service.  You could also query the task service for any tasks that are assigned to a particular user or group.  Or use some of the logging to figure out what happened during the call to startProcess(..).

Kris